# Count How many Radio Buttons were checked per group (Minimum of 2 Total Selections)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to validate 7 groups of Radio Buttons to make sure at least 2 groups were selected; if not show an alert.

I also have some other radio buttons on my page not related to these. They should not be included in this check.

Basically, I need at least 2 groups selected from all 7 groups.

I have tried a few methods posted in the community but none of them have worked.

```js
$('.counter').text($(':radio:checked').length);

$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  $('.counter').text($(':radio:checked').length);
});

// I also tried this:

/*
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function(){
   $('.totleft').text($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length+'/'+($('input[type="radio"]').length/2))
  });
/*/
```

````html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="group1" id="a" name="group1" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group1" id="b" name="group1" value="Reject" type="radio">
  <input class="group1" id="c" name="group1" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group1" id="d" name="group1" value="Reject" type="radio">
</div>
<div>
  <input class="group2" id="e" name="group2" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group2" id="f" name="group2" value="Reject" type="radio">
  <input class="group2" id="g" name="group2" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group2" id="h" name="group2" value="Reject" type="radio">
</div>
<div>
  <input class="group3" id="i" name="group3" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group3" id="j" name="group3" value="Reject" type="radio">
  <input class="group3" id="k" name="group3" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group3" id="l" name="group3" value="Reject" type="radio">
</div>
<div>
  <input class="group4" id="m" name="group4" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group4" id="n" name="group4" value="Reject" type="radio">
  <input class="group4" id="o" name="group4" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group4" id="p" name="group4" value="Reject" type="radio">
</div>
<div>
  <input class="group5" id="q" name="group5" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group5" id="r" name="group5" value="Reject" type="radio">
  <input class="group5" id="s" name="group5" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group5" id="t" name="group5" value="Reject" type="radio">
</div>
<div>
  <input class="group6" id="u" name="group6" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group6" id="v" name="group6" value="Reject" type="radio">
  <input class="group6" id="w" name="group6" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group6" id="x" name="group6" value="Reject" type="radio">
</div>
<div>
  <input class="group7" id="y" name="group7" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group7" id="z" name="group7" value="Reject" type="radio">
  <input class="group7" id="aa" name="group7" value="Accept" type="radio">
  <input class="group7" id="bb" name="group7" value="Reject" type="radio">
</div>
```
function VALIDATE_FORM() {
myFunction7();
var starttime = $("#start_time_1").val();
var endtime = $("#end_time_1").val();

//console.log(starttime);

if (starttime == '') {
    Swal.fire({
        title: "Start Time",
        text: "is REQUIRED!",
        icon: "error",
        showConfirmButton: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        timer: 3000,
        returnFocus: false,
    });

    document.getElementById('start_time_1').focus();
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
};
```
````

Comment: @freedomn-m Did you mean `$(':radio:checked').length < 2`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, that makes a little more sense...

Comment: @freedom-m Yes like that $(':radio:checked').length < 2 but it needs to be from all the groups

Comment: @Papin that selector will work for all groups.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var atLeastTwoAnswered = true;
$("input:radio[name^='group']").each(function(){
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  if($("input:radio[name="+name+"]:checked").length < 2)
  {
    atLeastTwoAnswered = false;
  }
});
alert(atLeastTwoAnswered);
```

While the alert will trigger on window load, you could add this to a certain event.

Comment: Would this affect my other Radio Buttons?

Comment: Edited the answer. Now the only radio buttons whose name start with `group` will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can give id attribute of input elements like this and run a for loop to check the status of radio buttons of each group:

```js
let totalCheckedGroupCount = 0;

for(let i=1; i<=3; i++) {
  const radioEl1 = document.getElementById("g_"+i+"_0");
  const radioEl2 = document.getElementById("g_"+i+"_1");
  
  if(radioEl1 && radioEl2 && radioEl1.checked || radioEl2.checked) {
    totalCheckedGroupCount++;
  }
}

console.log(totalCheckedGroupCount);
```

```html
<input id="g_1_0" name="group1" value="Accept" type="radio">
<input id="g_1_1" name="group1" value="Reject" type="radio" checked>

<input id="g_2_0" name="group2" value="Accept" type="radio">
<input id="g_2_1" name="group2" value="Reject" type="radio" checked>

<input id="g_3_0" name="group3" value="Accept" type="radio">
<input id="g_3_1" name="group3" value="Reject" type="radio">
```

Comment: my radio buttons are not checked as a default

Comment: I checked them just for demo purpose, you can uncheck them as per your requirement.

Comment: This worked the best for my code. Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you can wrap all the `radio` inputs in a form. When the form is submit you can check the `length` of all `:selected` radios and then allow/disallow the form submission as normal.

By wrapping the radios in a `form`, it restrict this logic so that it will ignore any other radio controls on your page.

```js
let $container = $('#radio-container');
let getSelectedRadioCount = () => $container.find(':radio:checked').length;
let updateRadioCounter = () => $('.counter').text(getSelectedRadioCount());

updateRadioCounter(); // on load
$container.find(':radio').on('change', updateRadioCounter); // on change

$('button').on('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (getSelectedRadioCount() < 2) {
    console.log('You need to select at last 2 radio options...');
  } else {
    console.log('Submit form here...');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radio-container">
  <div>
    <input class="group1" id="a" name="group1" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group1" id="b" name="group1" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group1" id="c" name="group1" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group1" id="d" name="group1" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="group2" id="e" name="group2" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group2" id="f" name="group2" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group2" id="g" name="group2" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group2" id="h" name="group2" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="group3" id="i" name="group3" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group3" id="j" name="group3" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group3" id="k" name="group3" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group3" id="l" name="group3" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="group4" id="m" name="group4" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group4" id="n" name="group4" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group4" id="o" name="group4" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group4" id="p" name="group4" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="group5" id="q" name="group5" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group5" id="r" name="group5" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group5" id="s" name="group5" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group5" id="t" name="group5" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="group6" id="u" name="group6" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group6" id="v" name="group6" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group6" id="w" name="group6" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group6" id="x" name="group6" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="group7" id="y" name="group7" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group7" id="z" name="group7" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group7" id="aa" name="group7" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group7" id="bb" name="group7" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="counter"></div>
  <button type="button">Check if valid</button>
</div>
```

Comment: my whole page is actually a full form

Comment: In that case, use ` div` instead of the form. I've updated the answer.

Comment: my form uses this <script>function VALIDATE_FORM() return true;</script> when we click the save button it validates the whole form. Should I put your code within but I won't need the button you added Thank you

Comment: is working as expected but i need to figure out how to add the code to my validation script

Comment: In that case just copy the content of the `button` click handler (Note *not the click handler itself*) in to your function.

Comment: just this ```   if (getSelectedRadioCount() < 2) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('You need to select at last 2 radio options...');
  } else {
    console.log('Submit form here...');
  }```

Comment: Yes - although you may not need `e.preventDefault()`, depending on how your function is invoked.

Comment: I'm getting an error 
       Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: As I mentioned above, you may not need that line, depending on how you call your function

Comment: Im using sweetalerts2 for the alerts     See my code on top I just edited

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question in that case, as the scope of this question has changed a lot from what you first asked.

Comment: is all part of the same radio buttons validation

Comment: Right, but since the question you've said that it's called via a function which wasn't shown or mentioned in the OP, and you're also saying something about it involved sweetalert2, which again wasn't mentioned or demo'd in the question. This is why I'd suggest starting a new question will ***all relevant details***

Answer (score 0):

You can map the selected groups per div, filter checked groups and count the result. The snippet does not use JQuery and uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

```js
const checkedGroups = _ => [...document.querySelectorAll(`#radio-container div`)]
  .map(v => v.querySelector(`[type='radio']:checked`))
  .filter(v => v).length;
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.type === `radio`) {
    const nChecked = checkedGroups();
    document.querySelector(`.counter`)
      .textContent = `Nr of checked groups: ${
        nChecked} ${nChecked >= 2 ? `(valid)` : ``}`;
    if (nChecked >= 2) {
      document.querySelector(`#cando`).removeAttribute(`disabled`);
    }    
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="radio-container">
  <div>
    <input class="group1" id="a" name="group1" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group1" id="b" name="group1" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group1" id="c" name="group1" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group1" id="d" name="group1" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="group2" id="e" name="group2" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group2" id="f" name="group2" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group2" id="g" name="group2" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group2" id="h" name="group2" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="group3" id="i" name="group3" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group3" id="j" name="group3" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group3" id="k" name="group3" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group3" id="l" name="group3" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="group4" id="m" name="group4" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group4" id="n" name="group4" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group4" id="o" name="group4" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group4" id="p" name="group4" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="group5" id="q" name="group5" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group5" id="r" name="group5" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group5" id="s" name="group5" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group5" id="t" name="group5" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="group6" id="u" name="group6" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group6" id="v" name="group6" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group6" id="w" name="group6" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group6" id="x" name="group6" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="group7" id="y" name="group7" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group7" id="z" name="group7" value="Reject" type="radio">
    <input class="group7" id="aa" name="group7" value="Accept" type="radio">
    <input class="group7" id="bb" name="group7" value="Reject" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="counter"></div>
  <button type="button" id="cando" disabled>submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Would this affect my other radio buttons?

Comment: Not if they are outside div#radio-container

Comment: Im using sweetalerts for alerts, how can i add your code to it? see my post I just updated it

Comment: I have presented you a way to determine if the user selected n groups, which was your question. You can use the answer (or not) for the rest of your code. If there are more questions concerning your code, please submit a new question.

Comment: I sure will, Thank you